# Display next value of a primary key in a textbox VB6

Tags: textbox, vb6, primary-key

I just want to know if there is a built-in function or way to get the next primary key in ms access database wherein it will be displayed in textbox in my vb form? I am using ADODB for my connection.. Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never came accross with a function giving the **Next Key** but I normally does is to `Select Max(ID) from table` and store it with +1 in the Textbox. That might help you

---

**Edit**

If you talk about my personal opinion on it I would create a Connection in SubMain() which I call at the start of the Application and Recordset will be created as and when required and close as soon the work is done. so if your application is ready to take the record when forms load the code will come on Form_Load() or else if it starts after clicking on a button then on BtnAddNewRecord_Click()

```
Private Sub BtnAddNewRecord_Click()
    Dim Rs1 As New adodb.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Set Rs1 = Conn1.Execute("SELECT Max(id) FROM <TableName>")
    TxtID.Text=Rs1(0) + 1
    Rs1.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: do i have to put it in the form load and establish the connection first using the adodb? can you give the syntax? thanks

Comment: Its a big comment so I am updating my answer

Comment: i am getting an error at 5th line of your code(TxtID.Text = RS1[0] + 1
the error says "Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement"

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the textbox is TxtID and not Text1

Comment: Thanks sir.. I got it now.. :)
I just have to change the [] to ()

Comment: Thanks mate. It pleasure that it worked for you. If you like the answer please upvote

Comment: Sir another thing. I have a button that when i click it the value from that textbox will automatically save in the database. However, when i click the button, the value in the Textbox doesn't change. How can I refresh the textbox? do i have to put the code in loop?

Comment: I think you Need to frame an another question with code and things u already tried and [follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: If this is an autonumber field the increment isn't guaranteed to be 1 anyway.  Don't expose primary keys in a user interface or you can expect trouble down the road.